# How to enable "Internet Connection Sharing" using command line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, netsh

Is there a way to enabled "Internet Connection Sharing" on **Windows 7 (or higher)** using **command line**? Perhaps using "netsh" or a similar command?

Answer (score 2):

I think this question should be on superuser.com. And it is there: https://superuser.com/questions/470319/how-to-enable-internet-connection-sharing-using-command-line.

If you are interested how to do it programmatically – here is the source code at GitHub: https://github.com/utapyngo/icsmanager.

Answer (score 1):

To manage "Internet Connection Sharing" under Win7 you must exec `net start SharedAccess` or `net stop SharedAccess`.

You can also configure the service using `sc config SharedAccess start= disabled` or `sc config SharedAccess start= auto` and some other.
Run `sc config` to know other options for the "start= ". The space between start=OPTION is mandatory.

Comment: how can i tell it which adapter's connection should be shared with which other adapter?

Comment: You can't i guess. Follow utapyngos answer :D please. The service configuration hasn't that power cows.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I want to use VirtualBox Host-only Adapter alone for two-way communication and Internet sharing, I use Powershell to achieve that.

```
# fix Windows 10 ICS not working after reboot
# https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4055559/ics-doesn-t-work-after-computer-or-service-restart-on-windows-10
[microsoft.win32.registry]::SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedAccess", "EnableRebootPersistConnection", 0x01)

# Enable IP Forwarding
# https://serverfault.com/questions/929081/how-can-i-enable-packet-forwarding-on-windows/929089#929089
Set-NetIPInterface -Forwarding Enabled
# Check IP Forwarding Status
Get-NetIPInterface | Select-Object ifIndex,InterfaceAlias,AddressFamily,ConnectionState,Forwarding | Sort-Object -Property IfIndex | Format-Table

# Change the Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) service Startup type to Automatic.
Set-Service SharedAccess -StartupType Automatic
# Start ICS service for now
Start-Service SharedAccess
# Check ICS service Status
Get-Service SharedAccess
```

Comment: SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedAccess", "EnableRebootPersistConnection", 0x01) -- just found out that this command breaks AnyConnect VPN client

Comment: OpenVPN Server - PowerShell line solved Internet persistency problem on WIndows 10 - [microsoft.win32.registry]::SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedAccess", "EnableRebootPersistConnection", 0x01)

Comment: For VPN Server - must add VPN Server Gateway IPs to Firewall Inbound due to VPN subnet is different network and firewall may not allow foreign packets to pass without explicit rule.

Answer (score -1):

1. Start cmd as admin and type the following
   `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=networkname key=networkpassword`
2. Press enter then type `NETSH WLAN start hostednetwork`
3. press enter again.

> remember to replace the networkname and networkpassword with your preferred names and password respectively

Comment: Creating a hosted network is a diffrent step from sharing another interface's connectivity within this network (ICS)